# Limiting number of characters in text area?

Tags: javascript

I'm having a text area, and I want to limit each line in the text area to have a limit of 20 characters, any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not easy to do in JavaScript unless you need to support only a small number of browsers (like one).  The complication is that when determining if a new key press event should actually result in the printable character getting appended you must know if the cursor position in the textarea is in a line which cannot accept any new characters.  The catch is that different browsers have different methods for determining the cursor location in a textarea.

If would suggest using jQuery and the [fieldSelection plugin](http://laboratorium.0xab.cd/jquery/fieldselection/0.1.0/test.html) and setting the event handler for the textarea in question as follows:

```
var maxChars = 20;
var textarea = document.form1.textarea;
textarea.onkeypress = function(ev) {
  // Trim any lines with length > maxChars.
  var lines = textarea.value.split(/\r?\n/);
  for (var i=0; i<lines.length; i++) {
    if (lines[i].length >= maxChars) {
      lines[i] = lines[i].substr(0, maxChars);
    }
  }
  textarea.value = lines.join("\n");
  // Determine if the keypress event should succeed.
  var keyPressZeroWidth = (ev.keyCode == 13) || //...
  var keyPressWouldMakeLineTooLong = // fieldSelection usage here...
  return keyPressZeroWidth || !keyPressWouldMakeLineTooLong;
};
```

Comment: You dont need to do it on keypress, you can do it post-wise and crop the entire value if needed.

Comment: @stefan - true, that would work, although any key typed that exceeds the max length will be visible briefly while the key is down until it is released.  Also if a character is entered in anything but the last column it will get inserted and trim the last character unless you track the cursor position.

Answer (score -1):

Use `cols` attribute in textarea

```
<textarea name=myText wrap=physical cols=20 rows=4></textarea>
```

**Update:**

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

function textCounter(field,maxlimit) {
if (field.value.length > maxlimit) // if too long...trim it!
field.value = field.value.substring(0, maxlimit);      
}

</script>    

<body>
<textarea name=message wrap=physical cols=20 rows=4 onKeyDown="textCounter(this.form.message,125);" onKeyUp="textCounter(this.form.message,125);"></textarea>  
</body>
```

Comment: It wont limit anything, it will just affect how the control is rendered. Ie width of the controller.

Comment: this will check for the whole text area ,i wont to check each rows max length